# Integrating Crawler Twitter and HBase

Tags: hadoop, solr, web-crawler, hbase

I have a twitter crawler which integrated to HBase via HBase native java client. When the crawling process begin, for each tweet in tweets will be sent to HBase table. My question, is it the best practice to Integrate Crawler and HBase ? I'm afraid about the performance while the crawling process is continued with saving tweets to table. ( I do these thing because after inserting data from crawler to HBase, those tweets will be indexed by Solr )

Comment: those tweets will be indexed by Solr or Cloudera Search ? Which one ?

Comment: those tweets will be indexed at solr, and could be search by user at the search column later

Answer (score 0):

In started,the table belong to one region.The write operation can consider as single-thread model.With amounts of data write into table,*split* will happen.Write operation will more faster.You can consider as multi-thread model now and then performance depend on the client's throughput.